# How to use mod_rewrite with Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm running a wordpress installation on the root dir of my website test.com
Wordpress is using url's like: test.com/information/ and I also added some custom parameters like: test.com/information/?about=product

I tried to use the mod-rewrite generator at http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ to change my custom urls to test.com/information/about/product but keep receiving a wordpress 404 error.

Is there a solution to my problem?

Comment: There is no difference in Wordpress url rewrite or general web page url rewrite. Your question is not clear. It looks you have one static url and you want another static url. Which one is your original url? and what will change as product change?

Comment: I use the following rule:
RewriteRule ^about/([^/]*)/$ /information/?about=$1 [L]

Comment: @Satya-Prakash if the "?about=" change, the title and content of the wordpress page (about) will change too

Comment: Also, make sure that your server actually has mod_rewrite enabled, because it sounds like it doesn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

All answers wrong. Login to admin area. On the left menu, under settings find `permalinks`. You can choose or add proper settings there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @borayeris - Wordpress has it's own permalinks page under Settings - use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using pretty permalinks, make an `about` page then make it the parent page of all your `product` pages.

Or use the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^information/about/([^/]+)/?$ information/?about=$1 [L,NC]
```